# Decimal to base 1

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-systems

Explain why base 1 radial expansions are impossible.

I think If **b** is a natural number greater than 1, to write the abbreviated base b radial expansion the number of symbols required is **b**.

For example, the digits 0, 1, and 2 are sufficient to write the abbreviated base 3.

But then, to write base 1 radial expansions is impossible because very such expansion would evaluate to 0. But I'm not sure. Can someone please explain to me why base 1 expansions are impossible, is there a theorem behind it?
Thanks

Comment: Hmm, I don't know whether they should be described as impossible, or just ugly, inconvenient, and radically different from all the other bases.

Comment: Since $1^n=1$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$, the notion of "place" doesn't really mean much in base $1$.

Answer (score 5):

Some people would consider the tally system to be "base 1." You only have one digit to use, so don't choose $0$, choose $1$.  Then, for instance,

$$5 = 1\times 1^4 +1\times 1^3 + 1\times 1^2 + 1\times 1^1 +1\times 1^0 =11111_1, $$

just like any other radix.

Comment: The major disadvantage of this system (besides the fact that numerals are O(n) rather than O(log n) in length) is that you can't do "decimal" fractions, because all the 1's to the right of the radix part are still just 1's.

Comment: @Dan  That's the same disadvantage that Roman numerals have.  And for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

Base $n$ radial expansions are possible, for $n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}$ precisely because

- The sequence $~n^1, n^2, n^3, \cdots ~$ grows unbounded.
- If $M \in \Bbb{Z^+}$, and $~n^k \leq M < n^{k+1} ~: ~k \in \Bbb{Z^+}, ~$ then you can choose an element $t$ from $\{1,2,\cdots,n-1\}$ such that $~~0 \leq (M - tn^k) < n^k.~~$  So, the number $M$ can be whittled down to $(M - tn^k)$ which will result in the leftmost digit in the base $n$ expansion of $M$ being $t$.

For $n = 1$, the 2nd consideration above becomes moot, because $~1^1, 1^2, 1^3, \cdots~$ does not grow unbounded.